# Set column value based on equal sized grouping

Tags: python, pandas

I want to add a column to a dataframe that groups it by equal number of rows.

Example:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame ( data = {'A':[11, 12, 13, 14, 15], 'B':[16, 17, 18, 19, 20 ] } )
df

Out[3]: 
    A   B
0  11  16
1  12  17
2  13  18
3  14  19
4  15  20
```

For group size 2 I want:

```
    A   B   Group
0  11  16     0
1  12  17     0
2  13  18     1
3  14  19     1
4  15  20     2
```

I tried:

```
step = 2
df[ 'group' ] = -1
for i in range ( 0, int ( df.shape[0] / step ) ):
    df[ i * step: ( i + 1 ) * step ]['group'] = i
```

But group is never changed from its initial value of -1

Comment: you can do directly without loop for with `df['group'] = np.arange(len(df))//step`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`pd.Index.repeat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.repeat.html#pandas.Index.repeat) then slice by length of `df`

```
df["Group"] = df.index.repeat(2)[:len(df)]
df
    A   B  Group
0  11  16      0
1  12  17      0
2  13  18      1
3  14  19      1
4  15  20      2
```

Answer (score 1):

So simple:

```
for i in range ( 0, df.shape[0]):
    df [ 'group' ][i] = int ( i / step )
```